# Docker environment variable cannot be covered in entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I used a env in Dockerfile and set a default value like this:

```
ENV HOST=abc
```

And I cover this env in docker-compose yaml file like follow:

```
environment:
    HOST: "efg"
```

But I `echo` this env in my entrypoint script, it is `abc`.

And use `docker exec` to run in the container to `echo $HOST`, it is `efg`.

Who can tell me why.

Comment: Can you add your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files to the question?

Comment: A debugging command you launch with `docker exec` isn't a child of the main container process (that is, the entrypoint); Docker injects it into the container environment from outside.  But for many practical purposes it will work to `docker run` a new container with a different command, and that will go through the normal entrypoint sequence.

Comment: I modify the environment variable name and it worked fine. So may it be a reserve ？My variable name is DATABASE_INSTANCE, and I change it to DATABASE_INS, all worked fine.